# UICollectionView Cell resizing issue

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard, ios13

I am new to iOS app development and I am trying to understand what is the issue in iPhone 11 Pro Simulator of my layout when works well in iPhone 8 Plus.

Please find the screenshot below:

[image]

Can anyone help me out on why this is happening?

If you require anymore information on the code, Please let me know.

**EDIT:**

This is my CollectionView Attributes:

[image]

It appears that the cell is little zoomed in when it comes to the iPhone 11 Simulator.

Comment: Get more information please. Is it test project? Could you share project via github?

Comment: Are you using any safe area layout guides?

Comment: Please check Size inspector of collectionview and check for Estimated Size option. Set it to None if it is automatic. Revert back if that works.

Comment: @StanislavKramarenko I'm sorry, it's a live project. I do not have enough permission to share it via Github

Comment: @BencePattogato I'm not using safe area layout guides. I have unchecked it.

Comment: @CrackIt I have given the Cell size as the maximum that it can reach. In this case, it's 414 Width and 150 height. Estimated Height is set to None but still, the error persists.

Comment: @Ümañgßürmån can you share the size for item method?

Comment: @CrackIt I've not given sizeforitem method, I've done everything via Storyboard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must have to implement Size for item method and need to confirm to `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`.

As every iPhone has different width you can not set to static width.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 150)
    }
```

Comment: Okay, I'll check using this code. Do I have to apply this everytime I use a Vertical Collection View?

Comment: Yes @Ümañgßürmån

Comment: Wow, This worked.. :)) Thank you so much. I'll remember to add this every time I use the CollectionView.